# Can't get a second AudioClip to start when the first clip stops

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Newbie coder.

Briefly, when a player clicks an onscreen button, a robot is instantiated, putters around for a moment, and a "running" sound plays. Once the robot runs out of power, the sound stops playing, and a new "stop" sound *should* play.

Everything works except that last part. I can't get the "stop" sound to play once the "running" sound stops playing. I handle that logic in the Update function.

```
private AudioSource 
    robotRun_big,
    robotStop_big;

private RobotMover robotMover;

// Omitted AddAudio() function that works fine.

void Awake()
{
    // Contains a variable I use as a timer
    robotMover = GetComponent<RobotMover>();

    // Declare and initialize an AudioClip
    AudioClip clipRobotRun_big = Resources.Load("SFX_19-23/robotRun_big") as AudioClip;

    // Initialize an AudioSource (declared as a private variable above)
    robotRun_big = AddAudio(clipRobotRun_big, true, false, 0.5f);

    // Same as above
    AudioClip clipRobotStop_big = Resources.Load("SFX_19-23/robotStop_big") as AudioClip;
    robotStop_big = AddAudio(clipRobotStop_big, false, false, 1.0f);
}

// This is handled elsewhere, but it determines which object player clicks
public void CheckGameObject(GameObject clicked)
{
    if(clicked.name == "RobotGrower")
        robotRun_big.Play(); // This works fine
}


void Update()
{
    if(robotMover.robotPower <= 0)
        robotRun_big.Stop(); // This works fine.

    if(!audio.isPlaying)
        robotStop_big.Play(); // This DOES NOT work fine.
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
if(robotMover.robotPower <= 0)
    robotRun_big.Stop();
    robotStop_big.Play();
```

And this:

```
if(robotMover.robotPower <= 0)
    robotRun_big.Stop();
    robotStopped = true;
if(robotStopped)
    robotStop_big.Play();
```

The robotStop_big clip plays fine if I play it from Awake or elsewhere. Just not there in Update with that logic. Obviously, I'm missing something. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
if(!audio.isPlaying)
    robotStop_big.Play();
```

Use:

```
if (!robotRun_big.isPlaying)
    robotStop_big.Play();
```

GameObject.audio will return one AudioSource component, however, it is not guaranteed that the AudioSource it returns is the same one that you want.  Since you are defining multiple AudioSources anyway, use them instead of the .audio accessor.

Barring that change, another thing to try would be making sure that the AudioClip that you put into the robotStop_big AudioSource is not set to 3D.  This may prevent you from hearing it.